# How to use XMLTABLE with multiple default namespaces

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My XML has multiple default name spaces, my below

```
    <BusMsg>
       <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01 General_head_001_001_01_20160503.xsd">
            <CreDt>2017-06-29T05:32:11.147Z</CreDt>
            <Prty>abc</Prty> 
            </AppHdr>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.05 SCT_pacs_008_001_05_20160503.xsd">
        <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
            <GrpHdr>
                <MsgId>NATAAU33XXX2017062918789018AK12503</MsgId>
                <CreDtTm>2017-06-29T05:32:11.147Z</CreDtTm>
                <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
                <SttlmInf>      
                    <SttlmMtd>abc</SttlmMtd>
                    <ClrSys>
                        <Cd>abc</Cd>
                    </ClrSys>
                </SttlmInf>
                <InstgAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BICFI>abcdd</BICFI>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </InstgAgt>
                <InstdAgt>
                    <FinInstnId>
                        <BICFI>abcde</BICFI>
                    </FinInstnId>
                </InstdAgt>
            </GrpHdr>
        </FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
    </Document>
</BusMsg>
```

I tried like below, but didnt work, its giving me null as output

```
SELECT f.PURPOSE
    FROM tem_table,
    XMLTABLE( xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01 urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.05'), '/BusMsg/Document' 
      PASSING XMLTYPE(tem_table.SOURCE_MESSAGE_TEXT)
              COLUMNS PURPOSE VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/GrpHdr/MsgId') f
    WHERE id = '5bf8356b2e63';
```

Any one idea having on how to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because your XML document has different default namespaces in various elements, doesn't mean you have to use **default** namespaces to put them apart.

The namespace mappings you declare in the `XMLTABLE` function are only relevant int he XQuery expressions of this `XMLTABLE` call.

If you want to match the namespace `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01` you have two options

- declare it as default namespace and don't prefix the elements/attributes in the XQuery expressions.
- assign it to a namespace prefix and also use that prefix in the XQuery expressions.

  ```
  XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01'
                       , 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.05' AS "n")
         , '/BusMsg/Document'
           PASSING XMLTYPE(tem_table.SOURCE_MESSAGE_TEXT)
           COLUMNS PURPOSE VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'n:FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/n:GrpHdr/n:MsgId'
  ) f
  ```

I've assigned the NS ending in ".01" as default namespace and did not prefix the elements in the main QPath expression. I've also assigned the alias "n" to the other namespace, and also prefixed the elements from that namespace in the `COLUMNS` XQuery expression.

I might have done some typos and it might be better reversed to have less namespace prefixes.

Comment: 1.how to declare two default name spaces at a time?
2. if it is prefix by 'n', I have to prefix them in original XML as well else prefixing in XPATH alone will work? for me its not possible to add prefix in XML

Comment: @PhalaniKumar The namespace prefixes are note relevant! Namespaces are only distinguished by their URI. Therefore, no need to change the XML if you use other prefixes. Just change the XQuery(XPath). Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: As you said its working fine. Since am getting null result I made the below change - I replaced XPATH /BusgMsg/n:Document with '//n:Document' then it worked. Please suggest me 1. how to use XPATH including BusMsg 2. how to avoid manual adding 'n' prefix as I am going to make XPATH dynamic in function
Note:- It didn't work after removing two default name spaces. Its working only if we mention namespaces as you said.

Comment: SELECT f.PURPOSE FROM temp_table, XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces(default 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01', 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.05' as "n"), '//n:Document'  PASSING XMLTYPE(temp_table.SOURCE_MESSAGE_TEXT) COLUMNS PURPOSE VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'FIToFICstmrCdtTrf/GrpHdr/MsgId') f WHERE temp_column= '477811d7-aa85-4601-a95f-5bf8356b2e63'